# Placing npm-modules inside .meteor directory with npm install

Tags: path, npm, installation, package.json

Is it possible to define the path to the directory where the `npm-modules` directory will be created, when `npm install` is used?

I've used...

```
meteor create myApp
```

... to create a barebones Meteor app. I've added a package.json file to the root of the `myApp` directory:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "neo4j": "^2.0.0-RC2"
  }
}
```

When I run...

```
$ cd /path/to/myApp
$ npm install
```

... it creates a folder named `node-modules` at the root of the `myApp` directory. This leads to an error when I call `meteor run`.

If I manually move the `node-modules` to `myApp/.meteor/node-modules`, then all is well.

Is there a change I can make to the `package.json` file, so that the call to `npm install` will create the `node-modules` directory exactly where I want it?

---

EDIT: Following @Inchoon Park's suggestion, I installed `meteorhacks:npm`, and created a packages.json file with the contents:

```
{
  "neo4j": "2.0.0-RC2"
}
```

Note that `meteorhacks:npm` requires the exact version of each dependency. `"neo4j": "^2.0.0-RC2"` (with the `^` character) is not permitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make things a lot easier, I would highly suggest using Meteorhacks's awesome npm package (https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm). Once you install the package, it automatically creates a package.json in your file directory where you can describe npm modules you would like to use in your app.